# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) while running phpunit

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, phpunit, docker

Am getting this error Segmentation Fault (core dumped) when I try to run my unit tests using phpunit.

Am stuck with this for 2 days now since I don't get a clue which is throwing this error.

My php version is,

**PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.13 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul  7 2014 18:54:55)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans**

and PHP unit version is,

**PHPUnit 3.7.25 by Sebastian Bergmann**.

and I run this command in my project root directory,
**> phpunit
Configuration read from /var/www/[project root]/phpunit.xml.dist
Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

P.S: I tried using **Zend.enable_gc=0** but no luck.

EDIT: My phpunit is running on a docker container and my DB is on a different container linked to the phpunit container. The docker container is built on a ubuntu 12.04. Is the error related to disk space or memory?

Comment: Have you tried commenting out all your tests and adding them back in one by one?

Comment: There are close to 300 tests and am very new to PHP.

Comment: Have you tried typing 'export USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0' ?

Comment: I experienced this today and it turned out to be caused by a coding error that resulted in an infinite loop.

300 may be a lot to try to isolate, but it might help to examine the functions you've changed most recently and ensure each of those is still working as expected.

Comment: Hi, Can you post codes, both the code that you are testing and your unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is too old but I am just answering it because recently I had the same problem. I tried all of the comments for your question but none solved my problem.

I solved it adding the **processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true"** in whitelist tag inside filter.

My scenario:

- PHP 7
- PHPUnit 5.7
- Xdebug 2.4.0

I tried a lot of different configurations as list each path inside my zf module, disable controllers tests, disable all tests and enable one by one, but I only solved it when open the PHPUnit filter example and see the **processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist=true** that I never have seen before. After add this parameter, all tests run as expected.

```
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">../src</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".phtml">../view</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```